# TextTrimming inside a scrollviewer

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Im trying to have a textblock inside a scrollviewer, and if the text exceds the scrollviewer width, have it trimmed.
The text should display the "..." indicating thre is more text, so that the user can scroll to see the rest of the text.

right now i have something like this, but the text trimming inst working.

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                                        <TextBlock  Margin="0,5,0,0" Text="{Binding Item.Name}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" FontWeight="SemiBold" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                                    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: So I imagine there's more requirements to it, so will put as a comment for now. However if you actually need horizontally scrolling, and aren't doing much resizing, you could just give the ScrollViewer a name (I forget if RT supports Relativesource, so a name does just as well) but just add like `MaxWidth="{Binding ViewportWidth, ElementName=ScrollViewerName}"` to your TextBlock and it will invoke your trim based on the boundary of the scrollviewers width.

Comment: I've tested your method, it does not work. I think it's the problem with the width of TextBlock. If the text's size is greater than its container, TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" will work, and in the mean time, the entire text can not be shown completely even when the TextBlock is nested to a ScollViewer, beacuse the text is already be trimmed. But in a scrollviewer, it actually doesn't limit the width of the TextBlock, so will TextTrimming not function, and the text will not be trimmed.